# Locking register usage for a certain section of code

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-optimization, cpu-architecture

Let's consider a situation where we are writing in C code. When the compiler encounters a function call, my understanding is that it does the following:

- Push *all* registers onto the stack
- Jump to new function, do stuff in there
- Pop old context off the stack back into the registers.

Now, some processors have 1 working register, some 32, some more than that. I'm mostly concerned with the larger number of registers. If my processor has 32 registers, the compiler will need to emit 32 push and pop instructions, just as base overhead for a function call. It would be nice if I could trade some compilation flexibility[1] in the function for less push and pop instructions. That is to say, I would like a way that I could tell the compiler "For function `foo()`, only use 4 registers. This would imply that the compiler would only need to push/pop 4 registers before jumping to `foo()`.

I realize this is pretty silly to worry about on a modern PC, but I am thinking more for a low speed embedded system where you might be servicing an interrupt very quickly, or calling a simple function over and over. I also realize this could very quickly become an architecture dependant feature. Processors that use a "Source Source -> Dest" instruction set (Like ARM), as opposed to an accumulator (Like Freescale/NXP HC08) might have some lower limit on the number of registers we allow functions to use.

I do know the compiler uses tricks like inlining small functions to increase speed, and I realize I could inform most compilers to not generate the push/pop code and just hand code it myself in assembly, but my question focuses on instructing the compiler to do this from "C-Land".

My question is, are there compilers that allow this? Is this even necessary with optimizing compilers (do they already do this)?

[1] Compilation flexibility: By reducing the number of registers available to the compiler to use in a function body, you are restricting it's flexibility, and it might need to utilize the stack more since it can't just use another register.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. There is no reason to push all registers and they certainly don't do that. Some registers are inputs, some outputs and some are never used so there is no reason to save them. Look up calling conventions and you'll see how it is done. The compiler certainly knows what registers it's using and can save their state if needed.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Oh alright, thanks.

Comment: Far too broad. This involves CPU, API, compiler optimisation, operating system/library, linker, etc. If you need a specific register usage, you very likely also need a specific code structure, which means Assembler (possibly inline). Also some compiler already allow to reserve global registers, but that often shows is worse than accepting some more save/restore instructions in the code. And this is from a MCU-view, not (just) larger irons.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to compilers, registers and function calls you can generally think of the registers falling into one of three categories: "hands off", volatile and non-volatile.

The "hands off" category are those that the compiler will not generally be futzing around with unless you explicitly tell it to (such as with inline assembly).  These may include debugging registers and other special purpose registers.  The list will vary from platform to platform.

The volatile (or scratch / call-clobbered / caller-saved) set of registers are those that a function can futz around with without the need for saving.  That is, the caller understands that the contents of those registers might not be the same after the function call.  Thus, if the caller has any data in those registers that it wants to keep, it must save that data before making the call and then restore it after.  On a 32-bit x86 platform, these volatile registers (sometimes called scratch registers) are usually EAX, ECX and EDX.

The non-volatile (or call-preserved or callee-saved) set of registers are those that a function must save before using them and restore to their original values before returning.  They only need to be saved/restored by the called function if it uses them.  On a 32-bit x86 platform, these are usually the remaining general purpose registers: EBX, ESI, EDI, ESP, EBP.

Hope this helps.

---

(I meant to just add a small example, but quickly got carried away.  I would add my own answer if this question wasn't closed, but I'm going to leave this long section here because I think it's interesting.  Condense it or edit it out entirely if you don't want it in your answer -- Peter)

For a more concrete example, the [SysV x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation.html) is well-designed (with args passed in registers, and a good balance of call-preserved vs. scratch/arg regs).  There are some other links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki explaining what ABIs / calling conventions are all about.

Consider a simple example of with function calls that can't be inlined (because the definition isn't available):

```
int foo(int);

int bar(int a) {
  return 5 * foo(a+2) + foo (a) ;
}
```

[It compiles (on godbolt with gcc 5.3 for x86-64 with `-O3`](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22intel%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22JYOwLgBAZg9jAUowEoDcAoJEBGBDATouBLshAN7oQT4CmYArviBAKwQBU0c8uA1ACYyfbjAi8yGAL7ogAAA%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g530%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-xc%20-O3%20-march%3Dhaswell%20-std%3Dgnu11%22%7D%5D%7D) to the following:

```
   ## gcc output
   # AMD64 SysV ABI: first arg in e/rdi, return value in e/rax
   # the call-preserved regs used are: rbp and rbx
   # the scratch regs used are: rdx.  (arg-passing / return regs are not call-preserved)
    push    rbp             # save a call-preserved reg
    mov     ebp, edi        # stash `a` in a call-preserved reg
    push    rbx             # save another call-preserved reg
    lea     edi, [rdi+2]    # edi=a+2 as an arg for foo.  `add edi, 2`  would also work, but they're both 3 bytes and little perf difference
    sub     rsp, 8          # align the stack to a 16B boundary (the two pushes are 8B each, and call pushes an 8B return address, so another 8B is needed)
    call    foo             # eax=foo(a+2)
    mov     edi, ebp        # edi=a as an arg for foo
    mov     ebx, eax        # stash foo(a+2) in ebx
    call    foo             # eax=foo(a)
    lea     edx, [rbx+rbx*4] # edx = 5*foo(a+2), using the call-preserved register
    add     rsp, 8          # undo the stack offset
    add     eax, edx        # the add between the to function-call results

    pop     rbx             # restore the call-preserved regs we saved earlier
    pop     rbp
    ret                     # return value in eax
```

As usual, compilers could do better: instead of stashing `foo(a+2)` in `ebx` to survive the 2nd call to `foo`, it could have stashed `5*foo(a+2)` with a single instruction (`lea ebx, [rax+rax*4]`).  Also, only one call-preserved register is needed, since we don't need `a` after the 2nd `call`.  This removes a push/pop pair, and also the `sub rsp,8` / `add rsp,8` pair.  ([gcc bug report already filed for this missed optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70408))

```
    ## Hand-optimized implementation (still ABI-compliant):
    push    rbx             # save a call-preserved reg; also aligns the stack

    lea     ebx, [rdi+2]    # stash ebx=a+2
    call    foo             # eax=foo(a)
    mov     edi, ebx        # edi=a+2 as an arg for foo
    mov     ebx, eax        # stash foo(a) in ebx, replacing `a+2` which we don't need anymore
    call    foo             # eax=foo(a+2)
    lea     eax, [rax+rax*4] #eax=5*foo(a+2)
    add     eax, ebx        # eax=5*foo(a+2) + foo(a)

    pop     rbx             # restore the call-preserved regs we saved earlier
    ret                     # return value in eax
```

Note that the call to `foo(a)` happens before `foo(a+2)` in this version.  It saved an instruction at the start (since we can pass on our arg unchanged to the first call to `foo`), but removed a potential saving later (since the multiply-by-5 now has to happen after the second call, and can't be combined with moving into the call-preserved register).

I could get rid of an extra `mov` if it was `5*foo(a) + foo(a+2)`.  With the expression as I wrote it, I can't combine arithmetic with data movement (using `lea`) in every case.  Or I'd need to both save `a` and do a separate `add edi,2` before the first `call`.

Comment: `volatile` registers are actually quite useless, as registers are typically kind of "local/temporary variables". OP talks about CPU registers, not peripheral registers. Note that your example is not what `volatile` in C means. A scratch register is a temporary (unnamed) variable.

Comment: @Olaf: Good observation on the use of the word 'volatile'.  Also, scratch registers as you point out are not precisely the same as volatile registers; however as volatile registers are often (but not exclusively) used for temporary storage of a value, they are still sometimes referred to as scratch registers and are far from useless.

Comment: Please don't use the term "volatile" in C context as you use it in other contexts. The implications are **very** different. You basically differentiate between local and global registers, as I tried to point out, that has nothing to do with `volatile` and one should not use the term in C in any other context. The global registers you list for x86 are actually the same as your first cathegory: hands of.

Comment: @Olaf The terms volatile and non-volatile registers are sometimes used in academic works. However, most people use caller-saved and callee-saved registers instead. I agree that this terminology is confusing in C since `volatile register` is legal. @Sparky There is no such thing as hands off registers. In fact, there is no third category. Also this answer is purely informative and doesn't actually attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @HadiBrais - It is indeed. informational.  The question presumes an incorrect model that must first be corrected.  I was lazy and did not go further.  The "hands off" category to which I referred is technically part of the non-volatile set.  That being said, there is still value in modeling it as an unofficial 3rd category--registers that the compiler does not use unless explicitly told to via assembly.  On the x86, this would includes the CRx registers as well as others.  Although they might not be general purpose registers, they are still registers.

Comment: @HadiBrais: I'm well aware what OP means. Problem is exactly the implications the keyword adds here. But I disagree that it's about caller vs. callee saved. It is about lifetime of the contents. Anyway, that's all exactly why I think the question it too broad. One could easily write a book to cover all aspects.

Answer (score 1):

> Push all registers onto the stack

No. In the vast majority of function calls in optimized code, only a small fraction of all registers are pushed on the stack.

> I'm mostly concerned with the larger number of registers.

Do you have any experimental evidence to support this concern? Is this a performance bottleneck?

> I could trade some compilation flexibility[1] in the function for less
>   push and pop instructions.

Modern compilers use sophisticated inter-procedural register allocation. By limiting the number of registers, you will most likely degrade performance.

> I realize this is pretty silly to worry about on a modern PC, but I am
>   thinking more for a low speed embedded system where you might be
>   servicing an interrupt very quickly, or calling a simple function over
>   and over.

This is very vague. You have to show the "simple" function, all call sites and specify the compiler and the target embedded system. You need to measure performance (compared to hand-written assembly code) to determine whether this is a problem in the first place.